# What are the rules for called shots?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optional-rules, locational-damage

1. The d20pfsrd presents variant rules for called shots [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/called-shots). The source information for this page claims they come from the core rules, but I can't find them in the Core Rulebook. What source can I find these rules in? Did I miss them in some Paizo book, were they carried over from 3.5e, or from somewhere else?
2. The rules presented above state that "A called shot is a single attack made as a full-round action." But the feats dealing with called shots say "Normal: You can make one called shot per round as a standard action." Which of these is true? Is a typical called shot a standard or full-round action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The page that you linked has a copyright notice that reads "Section 15: Copyright Notice - Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Ultimate Combat".  It looks like these rules are in Ultimate Combat, which is not part of the core rulebook.
2. This is a typo in the original printings that has been [officially errata'd](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mcz?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Combat):

> In the Called Shot Feats sidebar, in the Normal entry for both feats, change “standard action” to “full-round action”.

Comment: Nice catch with the Copyright Notice. Can someone with the book check if this inconsistency is present in the book as well?